# Adding image to SQL server without bulk load permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I'm trying to upload an image to our SQL server via a web form, but am getting this error when I try to run the script:

*Msg 4834, Level 16, State 1.
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.*

The web form uploads the image to our server, before running the below script and then deleting the image file from the server

```
UPDATE ourTable
SET NewImage = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'https://our-server.com/just-and-image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as img)
WHERE ID = 01
```

For various reasons we have to store the image in the DB rather than in a directory and we can't change the SQL perms.

Is there another, better way to do this?

Comment: If you don't have permissions and cannot change them, you will need to insert from the application - preferably using the bulk functionality it provides. Alternatively you could create some sort of background import process where you can simply "queue" an image to be uploaded. Maybe use [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Or consider not storing images in valuable SQL Server storage space (not just for the image but also think about backups, logging, any tech that _uses_ logging like AGs, repl, etc.) in the first place, and instead doing what most people do - put the file on a file system somewhere, and just put the _path_ in the database. While you _can_ store the blobs inside SQL Server, this works much better in demos than at scale. At scale, you really shouldn't.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the file as a `varbinary(max)` parameter then do `UPDATE ourTable SET NewImage = @image WHERE ID = @ID;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand As I mentioned above, storing the image in the DB is just a given. I would much prefer to store the images in our AWS S3 bucket as we do elsewhere, but it's not an option here.

Comment: Thanks @SMor, haven't used filestream but I'll take a look.

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, I've seen that Microsoft doesn't support image columns anymore and suggests varbinary(max) instead. This is a new table (not live with clients yet) so I'm hoping we can just switch to that and try the UPDATE that way. Looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: To be fair, "this is the way it has to be" is almost always not the whole story. And sometimes with enough evidence that they're doing it wrong you can convince decision makers to make a better decision.

Comment: The thing you need to understand here is that getting SQL Server to download things from the internet is not the way to go about this. You need an external tool or app to download it, then push it into SQL Server as a parameter

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep, I hear you. I've suggested S3 as a better option, we'll see. Interesting problem to solve though anyway.